# Matlab Installation Failure

Tags: software-installation, java, matlab

I have installed Matlab 2016a on ubuntu, then the matlab-supporter and matlab-supporter-dev packages via Terminal with defining Matlab directory. However when I launch Matlab I saw an error as shown on image.

[image: The Error Message]

Do you know if there is something wrong with Java packages?

Comment: There is a write permission error. Try to `chmod -R 777 ~/.matlab`. If it throws errors, try with `sudo`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. It worked but there is an interesting problem. I also need to solve it.

![Valid XHTML](http://i.hizliresim.com/g83563.png)

Comment: Good to hear! I post it as an answer then :)

Comment: To address your second error message: According to the following link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/258264-error-starting-matlab-without-admin-privilege , MatLab needs to be started once with administrator privileges in order to properly initialize. The commenter in that link was using the Windows version, but it couldn't hurt to try running MatLab once with `sudo` to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a write permission error. Try to

```
 chmod -R 777 ~/.matlab
```

If it throws errors, try with `sudo`.